# Lista de conjunções aditivas

Tags: sintaxe, conjunções

Faço-vos dois requerimentos:

### 1. Ademais

Como categorizar sintaticamente, por exemplo, a palavra `ademais`? Advérbio ou Conjunção aditiva? A Porto Editora [marca-a](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ademais) apenas como advérbio, mas não pode ser uma conjunção aditiva?

```
Eu vou para casa, ademais a minha casa é bela
```

Mas esta [lista](https://www.normaculta.com.br/conjuncoes-aditivas/) de conjunções aditivas não a contempla.

### 2. Lista de conjunções aditivas

Alguém me pode facultar uma lista, o mais exaustiva quanto possível, de conjunções aditivas? Lembro-me destas:

- e
- demais
- também
- ademais
- além disso
- aliás
- outrossim

Muito agradecido

Answer (score 1):

#### Função sintática

Sintaticamente, o termo *ademais* é classificado como *Adjunto Adverbial de Adição* ou *Inclusão*.

Para o termo supracitado ser classificado como *adjunto*, é necessário que esse seja uma locução prepositiva¹: *além de*, *a mais de*, *ademais de*.

O objetivo desse *adjunto adverbial* é expressar uma adição de ideias etc. Introduzidos pela locução prepositiva.

> Sobre desemprego, havia doença.
>      Além das notas ruins, faltava muito às aulas.
>      *Ademais d*os parentes (além dos parentes), vinham os convidados.
>      Todos ficaram, mesmo Ana.
>      Os visitantes já se foram, Daniel inclusive.

Talvez a confusão entre *advérbio* e *conjunção* seja pelo fato de ambos transmitirem uma ideia de adição/inclusão. Porém, encontrei nenhuma afirmativa que considere o termo *ademais* como uma *conjunção aditiva*.

O advérbio *ademais* é um conectivo equivalente a conjunções *e*, *nem* etc. E, como este, introduz orações coordenadas aditiva. O fato de ocorrer neste tipo de orações coordenadas não determina a pertença a uma subclasse diferente.

#### Conjunções aditivas

Como foi Como conjunções aditivas, temos²:

- *e*
- *mas*
- *nem (= e não)*
- *não só… mas (também)*
- *não só… como (também)*
- *bem como*
- *não só… mas ainda*
- *tanto… quanto*
- *tanto… como*

***Referências***

<sup>PESTANA, Fernando. **A Gramática para Concursos: TEORIA PROFUNDAMENTE COMPLETA E MAIS DE 1.300 QUESTÕES ATUAIS E COMENTADAS.** [S. l.]: Editora Método Ltda., 2013.</sup>
<sup>BECHARA, Evanildo. Os principais tipos de adjuntos adverbiais. In: BECHARA, Evanildo. **Moderna Gramática Portuguesa.** [S. l.]: Nova Fronteira, 2012.</sup>
<sup>ROCHA, Carlos. **Consequentemente, advérbio conectivo.** [S. l.], 27 abr. 2015. Disponível em: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/consequentemente-adverbio-conectivo/33457. Acesso em: 1 abr. 2019.</sup>

---

<sup>¹ A locução prepositiva é o conjunto de palavras, com valor de preposição, terminado em preposição essencial.</sup>
<sup>² Há apenas algumas das várias conjunções.</sup>

Comment: Fiz uma análise, deixei em https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/cb6e505200093bb21708d170c7b59b7e#file-5885-md. Caso queiras, posso editar minha resposta.

Comment: Esta frase está, portanto, errada? `vou para casa, ademais a minha casa é bela`. Não julgo!

Comment: Talvez não me tenha explicado, eu queria traduções para "furthermore"